# Page displays 'null' after authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm creating a simple PWA to draw in multiple data sources into one application. I'm currently trying to set up authentication using a combination of passport and the twitter-strategy.

After the user has successfully authenticated they're account, twitter redirects to the callback endpoint, with the valid user data.... essentially the auth has been successful. However, when sending the user back to the client side application a html document with the word null is presented, rather than the application.

With the following code, I expect:

- Twitter to return to callback URL
- Server to perform actions in `authSuccess` function
- Redirect to the provided url on the client
- `routes.js` to server the application shell via the catch all route
- Client application to boot and handle the URL served

Currently, only the first two steps are successful, and the app simply displays null (with the correct url in the address bar), rather than the expected output. Changing the location of the `writeHead()` call to `/` works, and the user is authenticated as expected ().

*routes.js*

```
let users = require('../controllers/userController');

app.get('/user/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failWithError: true
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('[Twitter] Auth success route hit');
    users.authSuccess(req, res);
  },
  function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('[Twitter] Auth failure route hit');
    users.authFailure(err, req, res, next);
  }
);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
   console.log('[Route] Catch All: ' + req.path);
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/index.html'));
});
```

*userController.js*

```
authSuccess(req, res) {
  console.log('[User Controller] User',req.user);

  // Set some cookies here

  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/user/profile'});
  // res.redirect('/user/profile');
  res.end();
}
```

Any help much appreciated. If you need more code, just ask :)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this tutorial : https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-twitter ? It should help you

Comment: I did, many moons ago, @jacquesy. Changing the code to match the tutorial more closely makes no difference. The user is authenticating successfully, I just can't return to the client at the required URL.

Comment: If I am not wrong, did you set up the callback url inside your Twitter app settings online ? It may be the problem